# Why does initializing a stack outside of a function perform faster than initializing a stack inside a function?

Tags: java, performance, stack

I'm doing a LeetCode problem and I noticed that my code performs faster when I initialize a Stack before declaring a function as such runs faster:

```
class Solution {
Stack <Character>myStack = new Stack<Character> ();
public boolean isValid(String s) {
    int sLen=s.length();
    if (sLen%2!=0)
        return false;    
    // Stack <Character>myStack = new Stack<Character> ();
    for(int i=0; i<sLen; i++){
        if ((s.charAt(i)==')')  && !myStack.empty() && (myStack.peek()=='(')) 
            myStack.pop();
        else if (s.charAt(i)==']'  && !myStack.empty() && myStack.peek()=='[')
            myStack.pop();
        else if (s.charAt(i)=='}'  && !myStack.empty() && myStack.peek()=='{')
            myStack.pop();
        else
            myStack.push(s.charAt(i));
    }     
    return myStack.empty();
}}
```

rather than declaring it inside the boolean function:

```
class Solution {
//Stack <Character>myStack = new Stack<Character> ();
public boolean isValid(String s) {
    int sLen=s.length();
    if (sLen%2!=0)
        return false;    
    Stack <Character>myStack = new Stack<Character> ();
    for(int i=0; i<sLen; i++){
        if ((s.charAt(i)==')')  && !myStack.empty() && (myStack.peek()=='(')) 
            myStack.pop();
        else if (s.charAt(i)==']'  && !myStack.empty() && myStack.peek()=='[')
            myStack.pop();
        else if (s.charAt(i)=='}'  && !myStack.empty() && myStack.peek()=='{')
            myStack.pop();
        else
            myStack.push(s.charAt(i));
    }     
    return myStack.empty();
}}
```

Comment: How many times are you calling `isValid`? And how much faster are you seeing?

Comment: where do you call this `isValid` method?

Comment: You do know that your first example re-uses one and the same object, while the second examle keeps creating new `Stack`s which each call to `isValid(...)`?

Comment: @Turing85. Right, I did not think about how many times I would be calling the function. Thanks!

Comment: Most likely reason is that leetcode is not measuring the time prior to entering the `isValid` method.

Comment: Also, the methods are not equal. In the first case, if the `Stack` is not empty,  the content will be transferred to the next call, you will not start with an empty `Stack`.

Comment: @Todd Leetcode runs this 73 times, and the faster one states that the code outperforms ~80% of other submitted code while the slower one outperforms ~40%.

Answer (score 1):

That's because in the first snippet, you initialize your `myStack` ony once, while in your second snippet, you initialize it inside a method and so the `myStack` gets initialized each time the `isValid` method gets called.